# OSX Server Xcode CI service Unexpected internal server error

Tags: git, continuous-integration, ssh-keys, osx-server, xcode-server

I'm setting up CI for iOS projects using OSX server and the Xcode service.

I am having trouble when I first run the integration, it always fails with the following error:

> Integration failed. Unexpected internal server error (source control error). See the integration's logs for more details.

Now I DID solve this, but I am not quite satisfied with HOW I did that. Basically I am adding a new SSH key to my git server for every new project I set up for CI. So whatever key is generated for me, I just copy/paste it into my git server.
But we all know there should only be ONE SSH key.

I'm having trouble finding a way to use the SAME key for all projects on osx server -> xcode, since I am checking out the code using the same user account...

Anyone facing this? how did you manage?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

oh finally got that. as always, it's about the questions you ask that will lead to the answers you seek.

Finally came across an Apple document that gave me the solution [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH15747).

The trick that I was missing was that the PRIVATE key is actually in **.ssh/id_rsa**.

So instead of generating a new ssh public/private key and copy these to the git server, all I do now is copy the public/private key pair to osx server -> Xcode -> My Repo -> Edit section.

And there, no need to add any keys to my git server in the future...

Hope this helps visitors!